# How to get information about which display server is running?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, display

I'm using **Ubuntu 15.10** and i want to know which display server is running. In first version of Ubuntu it is definitely **X server**, but recently i got updated my Ubuntu 15.10 and i came to know that some **Mir Server** packages are going to be installed so how will i know that either Mir is running or X Server?

Answer (score 18):

(Trying to improve @shcherbak answer.)

To get info about the **running *display server*** write in the console:

```bsh
ps -e | grep tty
```

The out put might be, for example:

```bsh
 1475 tty2     00:00:00 gdm-x-session
 1478 tty2     00:00:40 Xorg
 1489 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-session-b
```

One of the `tty*` results [is the terminal where you have the GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for#answer-481915) in your linux system (usually `tty7` though I use `tty2` in my example). Therefore, this should be the terminal where the [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) (X11, Mir, or whatever) is running.

For example, the results show `1478 tty2     00:00:40 Xorg`, so this would be running Xorg (that is, X11).

Shscherbak answer would just output the running processes that contain a capital X, "X". Among others, of course, Xorg, in case it is present. But if another display server is running, you miss the information. :)

Comment: It output nothing on my computer.

Comment: @ElouanKeryell-Even the `ps` and `grep` command are really basic commands of linux, therefore I can only infer that your computer does not uses the `tty7` for the GUI. I am sorry. https://askubunt-u.com/questions/27339/what-is-tty7-in-the-commandline#27444

Answer (score 6):

try look your process list:

```
ps -e | grep X
```

Comment: This would return the running processes that contain a capital X (e.g., Xorg), but would not show another display server if it is running.

Answer (score 0):

with Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

I needed a slightly different approach:

> ps -ef  | grep -i tty

shows me an entry that contains

> /var/run/sddm

so I currently use SDDM Display Manager.

next step:

Find out if Wayland or X is active ...